# The recurrent formula - the eigenvalues of the Laplacian for the Sierpinski gasket

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, chaos-theory

I am wondering if there is a recurrent formula to calculate the eigenvalues of the Laplacian for the Sierpinski gasket of any generation. Does anybody know about it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, anastasiiia: since you are a new user, I wanted to let
you know a few things about the site.
In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in
what context you encountered the problem,
and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from
telling you things you already know,
and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. And finally +1 interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

Dirichlet or Neumann boundary condition? Anyway, both cases are treated in this [paper by Teplyaev](http://homepages.uconn.edu/teplyaev/research/teplyaev1998-JFA-iSig.pdf). If it does not quite answer your question, you can ask the author directly. The email given in the paper is old, he's now at [UConn](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~teplyaev/).